# SQL Server Point in Time Restore Scenario

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Hopefully you can help out on this as I may be up a creek!

I am working with a database using the FULL recovery model. The database has had nightly database backups but their transaction log has never been backed up (according to SQL Server Management Studio).

If I restore from one of the old database backups, would it be possible to take a backup of the current transaction log and bring the restored database forward to a point in time prior to a terrible transaction that got pushed through?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the log has never been backed up, then it could have been shrunk or truncated at some point. otherwise, it would have just grown. It's also possible that it has changed to SIMPLE and back to FULL.

You have one option: try it...

Comment: +1 to you for easy rep earned. I was in a state of panic but fortunately this transaction log had never been shrunk, truncated, and the database had never been switched to SIMPLE. Success.